# How do I remotely invalidate user's servlet session on-the-fly?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a page where accounts with alpha permissions may access. The JSP checks the session for a attribute named `"AlphaPerm"`.

But the problem I'm struggling with is if I find a user is messing/abusing the alpha testing permissions, I want to stop him immediately. I can change his permissions in my database right away but that doesn't stop the abuser right away.

A possible solution is checking my database every time my users do something, But I don't want to do that because that would slow the database down.

So how do I kill his session on-the-fly (Creating a admin page is my plan, but how do I get the users session object)? Basically I want to make a admin page so I can BAN a user.

Comment: How are you checking if the user is `messing` with the alpha pemission?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav just in case if one of my alpha testers go crazy......

Comment: Wait, you might have miss understood my question. I want to invalidate his session. that's all I want to do, through maybe a admin page.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav I'm sorry, I miss understood you're question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep references to user sessions by implementing an `HttpSessionListener`. [This example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/) shows how to implement a session counter, but you could also keep references to individual sessions by storing them in a context scoped collection. You could then access the sessions from your admin page, inspect their attributes and invalidate some of them. [This post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/360149/Servlets/java/users-system) may also have useful info.

**Edit**: Here's a sample implementation (not tested):

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    static public Map<String, HttpSession> getSessionMap(ServletContext appContext) {
        Map<String, HttpSession> sessionMap = (Map<String, HttpSession>) appContext.getAttribute("globalSessionMap");
        if (sessionMap == null) {
            sessionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpSession>();
            appContext.setAttribute("globalSessionMap", sessionMap);
        }
        return sessionMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        Map<String, HttpSession> sessionMap = getSessionMap(event.getSession().getServletContext());
        sessionMap.put(event.getSession().getId(), event.getSession());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        Map<String, HttpSession> sessionMap = getSessionMap(event.getSession().getServletContext());
        sessionMap.remove(event.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

You can then access the session map from any servlet:

```
Collection<HttpSession> sessions = MySessionListener.getSessionMap(getServletContext()).values();
```

Comment: This is interesting and seems to be going in the right way, but I'm a little dumb and I can't quite understand how they are doing it. I was hoping for something like this: tomcatServletStuff.getSessionByID(somGuyzID) and this method will return a Session object

Comment: Edited my answer to include a sample implementation.

Comment: Any idea why my imaginary method did not exist?

Comment: There used to be a method `HttpSessionContext.getSession("id")` but it is now deprecated. My understanding is that for security reasons, they don't want to make it too easy to access another user's session.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question checking against the `DB` is definitely a bad thing.

Also you must be comparing some values against some other standard values to decide if the user is messing around.
So an alternate to DB checking you can store these values in the user session and check for those values.

Also instead of creating an Admin page (probably a JSP page) I would suggest using a `ServletFilter` to do this work.

Also One thing I would personally suggest is instead of invalidating the whole session, you should put some restrictions on the users either for some time or till next login (for example restricting the access of some resource).

Comment: So for example using a filter you can check to see if the user has been restricted or not. If yes then you can forward his/her request (for the pages he is messing with) to some error page telling him what he/she has done wrong and why he is being restricted.

Comment: Does the filter need to check my database? I'm not sure how filters work

Comment: If you have everything in session then you won't need the DB checking.